# Is leaving a role for the second time after only a short return going to reflect badly for future employers?

Tags: resume, resignation

I began my career at large Company A. I worked there for several years, the last two of which were on a team that had begun imploding. I left Company A and worked for large Company B, also for several years.

I was due for a promotion and a change of pace when I was contacted out of the blue by a former coworker. The team I left at Company A had gone through a nearly complete change of people and re-invented itself. A bit of sanity checking the truth of the re-invention and some extensive soul searching (and probably some carelessness caused by a significant pay increase in the offer) led me to return to Company A where I've been for a few months.

Turns out the re-invention of the team is quite true. However, the overall company culture has not changed (not surprising for 150K employees) and I don't get along with it as well as I had expected. As much as I do like the people I work with, I'm struggling to avoid depression staying in that environment.

Is a return to a previous role and company followed by a relatively swift departure going to reflect badly down the road?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shouldn't, sometimes jobs just don't work out. In your case your previous two jobs spanned years rather than months. It won't be thought of as job hopping because it's not a trend, it's just a single instance.

If it's affecting you mentally, then it's best to move on if you cannot resolve the issues in situ.

The one place where you may have an issue is with Company B, it's unlikely that you could step back into a promotion after leaving them. Not impossible, but unlikely.